# how Assign id to each input box in created with javascript?

Tags: javascript

- ```js
  /* information in each game tree node */
     var node_size = 17; // number of elements of each game tree node
     var slot_node_id = 0;
     var slot_node_level = 1;
     var slot_number_childs = 2;
     var slot_id_first_child = 3;
     var slot_value = 4;
     var slot_x_pos = 5;
     var slot_y_pos = 6;
     var slot_alpha = 7;
     var slot_beta = 8;
     var slot_node_id_parent = 9;
     var slot_current_child = 10;
     var slot_best_child = 11;
     
     /* tree information */
     var gameTreeArray; // array having the game tree
     var tree_height; // game tree height
     var tree_number_nodes; // total number of nodes
     
     /* draw parameters */
     var tx=17; // triangle size_x = 2*tx
     var ty=17; // triangle size_y = 2*ty
     
     /* simulation parameters */
     var setinterval_id;
     var current_node_id=0;
     var previous_node_id=-1;
     var returned_child_value=0;
     var step_minimax=0; // current step of algorithm
     var simulation_mode=0; // 0-stop; 1-animated simulation; 2-step-by-step simulation
     
     // constants
     var MINUS_INFINITY = -1000; // or -Number.MAX_VALUE;
     var PLUS_INFINITY  = +1000;
     var simulation_cycle = 800; // cycle time (ms)
     
     /* draws node shape and changes node color to white*/
     function draw_node(context, idx_node, fill_color) {
      var cx = gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_x_pos];
      var cy = gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_y_pos];
      context.fillStyle = fill_color;
      if (gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_node_level] % 2 == 0) { // draw max player triangle node
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(cx, cy-ty);
       context.lineTo(cx-tx, cy+ty);
       context.lineTo(cx+tx, cy+ty);
       context.lineTo(cx, cy-ty);
       context.stroke();
       context.fill();
       context.closePath();
       var yy = cx - tx*8 - 25;
          context.fillStyle = "black";
          var oldFont=context.font;
          context.font="6pt Arial";
          context.font=oldFont;
      if (gameTreeArray[idx_node+slot_number_childs]>0) { 
          var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
          x.setAttribute("type", "text");
          x.setAttribute("value", "");
          x.setAttribute("placeholder", "a");
          x.style.left=yy+"px";
          x.style.top= cy-20+"px";
          document.body.appendChild(x);
      }
     } 
      else { // draw min player triangle node
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(cx, cy+ty);
       context.lineTo(cx-tx, cy-ty);
       context.lineTo(cx+tx, cy-ty);
       context.lineTo(cx, cy+ty);
       context.stroke();
       context.fill();
       context.closePath();
       var yy = cx - tx*8 - 25;
          context.fillStyle = "black";
          var oldFont=context.font;
          context.font="6pt Arial";
          context.font=oldFont;
       if (gameTreeArray[idx_node+slot_number_childs]>0) {
           var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
           x.setAttribute("type", "text");
           x.setAttribute("value", "");
           x.setAttribute("placeholder", "b");
           x.style.left=yy+"px";
           x.style.top= cy-20+"px";
          document.body.appendChild(x);
      }
      }
   context.fillStyle = "black"; // controls text color
      if (gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_number_childs]==0) // draw value if is terminal node
  context.fillText(gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_value], cx-4, cy+ty+16);
       
     }
     
     
     function create_game_tree() {
      if (simulation_mode==1) clearInterval(setinterval_id);
      simulation_mode=0;
      
      var stringToSplit = document.form1.treestructure.value; 
      var arrayOfStringsInnerNodes = stringToSplit.split(" ");
      stringToSplit = document.form1.utilvalues.value;
      var arrayOfStringsLeafNodes = stringToSplit.split(" ");
      var len1=arrayOfStringsInnerNodes.length;
      var len2=arrayOfStringsLeafNodes.length; 
      tree_number_nodes = len1 + len2; // total number of nodes
      gameTreeArray = new Array(tree_number_nodes * node_size); // total size of the array
      // first loads into the array the inner nodes
      var dp=0; // node depth
      if (len1>0) {
       gameTreeArray[slot_node_level]=dp; // depth of root node
       gameTreeArray[slot_node_id_parent]=-1; // parent id of root node
       gameTreeArray[slot_alpha]=MINUS_INFINITY; // init alpha value of root node
       gameTreeArray[slot_beta]=PLUS_INFINITY;  // init beta value of root node
      }
      for (var i=0,j=0,id_first_child = 1; i < len1; i++, j+=node_size) {
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_node_id] = i;
       if (gameTreeArray[j+slot_node_level] % 2 == 0)   
        gameTreeArray[j+slot_value] = MINUS_INFINITY; // max player initial value
       else
        gameTreeArray[j+slot_value] = PLUS_INFINITY; // min player initial value
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_current_child] = -1;
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_number_childs] = parseInt(arrayOfStringsInnerNodes[i],10);
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_id_first_child] = id_first_child;
       dp = gameTreeArray[j+slot_node_level];
       for (var child=0; child < gameTreeArray[j+slot_number_childs]; child++) {
        gameTreeArray[(id_first_child+child)*node_size + slot_node_level] = dp+1; // depth of child
        gameTreeArray[(id_first_child+child)*node_size + slot_node_id_parent] = i; // parent id
     
       }
       id_first_child += gameTreeArray[j+slot_number_childs];
      }
      // second loads into the array the leaf nodes (terminal nodes)
      for (var i=0,j=len1*node_size; i < len2; i++, j+=node_size) {
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_node_id] = i+len1;
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_number_childs] = 0; // terminal/leaf node
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_id_first_child] = -1; // because is a terminal/leaf node
       gameTreeArray[j+slot_value] = parseInt(arrayOfStringsLeafNodes[i],10);
      }
     
      tree_height = dp+1;
      prepare_draw_tree(len2);
      
      draw_tree();
     }
     
     
     function prepare_draw_tree(numLeafNodes) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasab');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;
      var top_margin_h = 30; // top margin defined for canvas
      var bot_margin_h = 40; // botton margin defined for canvas
      var h_util = h - top_margin_h - bot_margin_h;
      
      for (var i=tree_number_nodes - numLeafNodes, j=1, idx_node=i*node_size; i<tree_number_nodes; i++, j++,
     idx_node+=node_size) {
       gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_y_pos] = parseInt(top_margin_h + (h_util*gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_node_level])/tree_height);
       gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_x_pos] = parseInt((w/(numLeafNodes+1))*j);  
      }
      
      for (var i=tree_number_nodes - numLeafNodes - 1, idx_node=i*node_size; i>=0; i--, idx_node-=node_size) {
       gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_y_pos] = parseInt(top_margin_h + (h_util*gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_node_level])/tree_height);
       var fc_idx = gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_id_first_child] * node_size;
       var lc_idx = (gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_id_first_child] + gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_number_childs] - 1) * node_size;  
       gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_x_pos] = (gameTreeArray[fc_idx + slot_x_pos] + gameTreeArray[lc_idx + slot_x_pos])/2;
      }
     }
     
     
     function draw_tree() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasab');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = canvas.width; // resets canvas
      context.strokeStyle = '#000';
      context.lineWidth   = 1;
     
      for (var i=0, idx_node=0; i<tree_number_nodes; i++, idx_node+=node_size)
       draw_node(context, idx_node, "white");
     
      // draw line segments
      for (var i=0, idx_node=0; i<tree_number_nodes; i++, idx_node+=node_size) {
       var id_first_child = gameTreeArray[idx_node+slot_id_first_child];
       var number_childs = gameTreeArray[idx_node+slot_number_childs];
       var bx = gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_x_pos];
       var by = gameTreeArray[idx_node + slot_y_pos] + ty;
       for (var child=0; child < number_childs; child++) {
        var ex = gameTreeArray[(id_first_child+child)*node_size + slot_x_pos];
        var ey = gameTreeArray[(id_first_child+child)*node_size + slot_y_pos] - ty;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(bx, by);
        context.lineTo(ex, ey);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
       }
      }
     }
  ```

  ```html
  <form name="form1" method="POST" class="smart-blue">
     <h1>minimax game search algorithm with alpha-beta pruning 
     <br></h1>
     <label>
     <br>
     Enter the game tree structure: 
     <input name="treestructure" type="text" size="50" value="3 3 3 3">
     </label>
     <br>   
     <label>
     <br>
     Enter the game tree terminal values:
     <input name="utilvalues" type="text" size="50" value="3 12 8 2 4 6 14 5 2">
     </label>
     <br>
       <br>
     <button type="button" value="Change game tree" onclick="create_game_tree()" name="definetree" class="button">
     Create new game tree
     </button>
     <br>
     <br>
     </form>
     <canvas id="canvasab" width="900" height="600">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas!
     </canvas>
  ```
  -

---

well i have this code that will create a tree and along with the tree a input box will be generated based on the the number of nodes in the tree(except for the leaf nodes) now what i want is how can i make the each input box to be for each node like the first input box to be for the first node and the second to be for the second not and it goes like that

because i want to add a check answer butoon to check if the input box value will equal the node value and to do that the input boxes must have id to refer to a particular node or something like so that it can check it correctly.

the input boxes are created in javascript it self not on html.

i hope you guys understand what i mean.
run the snippet to see. sorry for the long code.

i'll appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: How are you supposed to determine which id is associated with which input? Why not assign the ID when you create the input? If you do add the IDs later, why not use that same process to find the appropriate box without traversing through them all to assign the ID?

Comment: Keep in mind when tagging, Java is different than javascript